# Windows Small Business Server Default Web Site Bindings

Tags: windows, iis-7, exchange-2010

I am running a new install of SBS 2011. The default website like all installs of IIS has bindings for net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq, msmq.formatname.

Are these bindings required? I usually delete them on production servers, but on SBS  I'm not sure if ActiveSync or OWA uses them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are used for Remote Web Workplace and TS Gateway. I have seen where a person deleted the last two and broke TS Gateway.

SBS's are too finicky to mess with the fine details in my experience.